# LibGDX visibility

Tags: java, libgdx

Is there a way to check if my sprite is visible? For instance I have a specific sprite I want to appear only IF this other sprite isn't visible. Example "You Win" will only appear if you win the game and the "You Lose" sprite isn't already on the screen. Thanks!

Comment: why not use a simple boolean called win and other called loose? `if (win && !loose) winSprite.draw(batch);` or to make it more readable just set `win = false;` and `loose = false;` each time they either loose or win, and draw it `if(win) winSprite.draw(batch);` and same with loose?

Comment: Not sure hat you want to achieve: Do you want to check the visibility (like in a test) or do you want to control it (like `sprite.setVisibile()`)?

Comment: It sounds to me like poor design to try to use various sprites' visibility to track the state of the game. That will become very convoluted.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of sprite can be maintained by extending Sprite class. Add data member in your extended Sprite Class and at run-time check your sprite is visible of not.

you can also fulfill your requirement by this :

```
    private Sprite win,loose;
    private SpriteBatch spriteBatch;
    private DialogType dialogType;

    @Override
    public void create () {

       dialogType=DialogType.NONE;

       spriteBatch=new SpriteBatch();

       win=new Sprite(...);
       loose=new Sprite(...);

    }

    @Override
    public void render(float delta) {

     Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
     Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    spriteBatch.begin();
    ...
    ...
    if(dialogType==WIN){
        win.draw(spriteBatch);
    }else if(dialogType==LOOSE){
        loose.draw(spriteBatch);
    }
    spriteBatch.end();

    }

public enum DialogType {    
       NONE,WIN,LOOSE 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like an overwhelm to do what you are trying to do, like I said in the comment with a simple `boolean win,loose;` you pretty much cover your example, or like other comment said you should not track the game state according with some sprite visibility make a enum and track the game state instead, like the other answer, BUT ima give you a solution

Use `Image` instead...

```
Image image =  new Image(texture);
image.setBounds(0,0,100,100); // set x,y,width,height
stage.add(image); //add to stage

image.setVisible(false); //make it invisible
image.setVisible(true); //make it visible
image.isVisible(); //check if is visible
```